# Solr with duplicate unique keys ?? Where am I wrong

Tags: solr, solrj, solarium

How it could be possible solr can have duplicate unique keys ?
When i tried something to update with given rId , instead of updating it create new doc

Here is the schema.xml

```
     -->

 <fields>

<field name="rId" type="string" required="true" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
<field name="filterId" type="string" required="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="createrId" type="string" required="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="userId" type="string" required="true"  stored="true"/>
<field name="desc" type="text_general" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>

<field name="value" type="text_general" indexed="true" required="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="fValue" type="string" indexed="true" multiValued="false"/>

<field name="country" type="text_general" indexed="true" required="false" stored="true" />
<field name="state" type="text_general" indexed="true" required="false" stored="true" />
<field name="city" type="text_general" indexed="true" required="false" stored="true" />
<field name="area" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false"/>
<field name="subArea" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false"/>
<field name="physical" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  </fields>

  <uniquekey>rId</uniquekey>
  <copyField source="value" dest="fValue"/>
```

**NOTE : rId is being sent from by me which will be unique. It is not autogenrated by Solr**

And here is snippet of SolrConfig.xml . I am using below update handler

```
<requestHandler name="/update/filter" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler"></requestHandler>
```

But I am getting duplicate rId (unique keys).

Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check overwrite attribute of add command as it determines whether Solr will keep multiple versions or not. If it is set to false then you will have different docs with same id. By default it is set to true